# Does PS4 saved game data from the physical edition transfer to the digital version?

Tags: ps4

I just bought Digimon Story Cyber Sleuth physical copy a few days ago. If I buy a Digital copy to get the dlc, do I have to delete my saved game?

Comment: No you will not have to delete your save game to get dlc. Not sure what the DLC is, but you may have to start a new game for it to be useful or see it right away. Some games have odd placement for DLC.....like Tomb Raider....

Comment: Thanks for letting me know when I get off work I'll getting the physical Digital copy

Answer (score 2):

The saved game is stored on the hard drive, not on the physical disc.  As long as you have a copy of the game (physical or digital) your save game will work.  The only exception to this is in the case of a new edition of a game, but this occurs rarely outside of games with separate editions in separate global regions.

Answer (score 0):

When you purchase the digital game, the PSN will recognize your license and turn your local phisical game copy into a digital one, without losing any data. Unfortunately, in some situations, your game might be "edition specific" (in the sense you will have to re-download it, and your saves might or might not work), but this thing happening is pretty rare.